# how to load Cake\Core\Configure in plugin

Tags: class, cakephp-2.0

i want to use Cake\Core\Configure in plugin
my code is :

> use Cake\Core\Configure;

before class and in function my code is :

> Configure::check();

but show me this error

> Error: Class 'Cake\Core\Configure' not found

Comment: I have a similar issue, did you find a solution?